# Javascript dropdown changing style display not working

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I have a table with 2 rows, each row with an ID to toggle the visability:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>'.$text_tier_show.':</td>
        <td>
            <select name="showart" onchange="show_toggle(this.value)">
              <option value="">-- Bitte Show w&auml;hlen --</option>
              <option value="1">Vliesshow</option>
              <option value="2">Tiershow</option>
              <option value="3">Gymkhana</option>
              <option value="4">Nachzucht Hengst</option>
              <option value="5">Nachzucht Stute</option>
            </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="gkanreise" style="display:none;">
        <td></td>
        <td>Gymkhana anreise</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="nachzucht" style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="2">Nachzuchten</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

On default both rows are hidden, but when someone clicks on the third of the dropdown I want to show the first row and for the 4. and 5. of the dropdown I want to show the second row.

The javascript I use is the following:

```
function show_toggle(show){
    var g = document.getElementById("gk_anreise");
    var n = document.getElementById("nachzucht");
                g.style.display = 'none';
                n.style.display = 'none';
    switch(show){
      case 3:
                g.style.display = 'block';
        break;
      case 4:
                n.style.display = 'block';
        break;
      case 5:
                n.style.display = 'block';
        break;
    }
}
```

But the whole thing isn't working. Doen't matter what i choose in the dropdown, it's not showing anything.
Can someone help me please.
Thanks you in advance for the help.
Burzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change id

from `document.getElementById("gk_anreise");` to `document.getElementById("gkanreise");`

also convert `show` from `string` to `int`

```
switch(parseInt(show)) {
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/bimido/1/edit?html,js,output